# Finding the number of repetition of a letter in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm getting a string and an integer as input which indicates up to which number of letters the given string can repeat (e.g. if the input is aba and 10, the actual string should be like abaabaabaa). I then want to evaluate the number of times the letter 'a' has been repeated, which in the above example is supposed to be 7.
Here's how I thought the code is supposed to be, meanwhile it does not work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count=0, num=0, n;
    string s;
    cin>>s>>n;
    for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='a')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i]=='a' && n%(s.length())!=0)
        {
            if(n%(s.length())>=i)
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
    num += ( (n/(s.length()))*count);
    cout<<num<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From your provided code it feels like you don't get your problem at all and just want us to solve it for you.

Comment: `if(n%(s.length())>=i)` I guess it should be `i < n%s.length()`. Easier to simply use `for(int i=0; i < num%s.length(); i++)` and avoid the additional test

Comment: @Liana: there are some rules in this site, the community can't be abused, sorry. If you seek for help you should really do your best to explain what you did and how it failed.

Comment: @Hack06 Sorry, i don't understand you. In this code, it is enough to replace `>=` by `>` to make it work, if I am not wrong. Difficult to say that OP did not make any effort.

Comment: Ok, I must have misread the question, sorry.

Comment: @Hack06 , I really don't understand. My code already works in some cases, and fails some. How have I abused the community by asking for help?

Comment: @Damien Thank you :')